# Re indexing 'catalog url Rewrites' and 'product flat data' causing an internal server error in magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento-1.7

Re indexing 'catalog url Rewrites' and 'product flat data'  giving me an internal server error in magento 1.7. which says..
**Internal Server Error**
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Instead of these two all other indexing is working fine. please help me !

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your/magento/shell/indexer.php -- --reindex catalog_url` to reindex using the shell and post the error message (if any).

Comment: thanks for helping me ,But I don't know how to use/run shell script for a live site

Comment: Ask the provider of your live site if they support SSH client access. If so, they'll usually give you some SSH credentials (host, username, password) which you can use to connect to the live site using some SSH client (like PuTTY for example). After successfully being connected, just type the command into the console and press Enter.